# Time round up quarter without condition

Tags: javascript, math

I need to round up quarter my time even if I'm on the current quarter.
Here is my code :

```
const currentDate = new Date(2020, 1, 8, 9, 42, 0, 0);
let roundedUpQuarter = Math.ceil(currentDate.getMinutes() / 15) * 15 % 60;
```

So in my exemple the current time is `09:42` so in my `roundedUpQuarter` variable I'll get the good result `09:45`
But I have a problem when I send 0, 15, 30 or 45 minutes on my current time because I need to round up too.

For an example if my current time is `09:30` I need to get `09:45`

I don't want to use `if condition` to do that. It's possible to do this only with a formula ?

Comment: Simply adding `+ 1` to the minutes should work (42 -> 43 will round up to 45, 44 -> 45 will round up to 45, 45 -> 46 will round up to 0) https://jsfiddle.net/f5d1rc9t/

Comment: @blex Smart ! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const currentDate = new Date(2020, 1, 8, 9, 42, 0, 0);
let roundedUpQuarter = Math.ceil((currentDate.getMinutes()+0.1) / 15) * 15 % 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `% 15 === 0` and add 1 minute to real minutes. Than continue with your equation.

```
const currentDate = new Date(2020, 1, 8, 9, 45, 0, 0);
var minutes = currentDate.getMinutes() % 15 === 0 ? (currentDate.getMinutes() + 1) : currentDate.getMinutes();
let roundedUpQuarter = Math.ceil(minutes / 15) * 15 % 60;

console.log(roundedUpQuarter); // for 45 return 0
```

Comment: That `%` check is not really necessary: https://jsfiddle.net/f5d1rc9t/

Comment: @blex: you're right... I won't change my answer, Matt has the solution you're writing about.